# Change TailwindCSS-Flowbite Drawer background color effect

Tags: laravel, tailwind-css, flowbite

If I add a Drawer and toggle it, the background behind the opened drawer  turns into gray with an opacity.
Is there a way to avoid this behavior and stay just on the original color?

[image]

Comment: You can remove all the class that has a `bg-` at start

Comment: @xenooooo I can? Awesome! How I can do that?

Comment: just remove the `bg-gray-900 bg-opacity-50` inside the `class` of your div

Comment: thx. But it is not my class and my div. It is display by TailwindCSS if I open the drawer. If I do in my CSS `div { @apply bg-transparent } nothing happens. The snippet in my Question is a screenshot from Chrome dev tools.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Solution

Go into your HTML, Blade or whatever you use for your Markup.
There, go into the element where you use the drawer.
Insert:

```
data-drawer-backdrop="false"
```

If you want to turn it on again, you can delete this line (because the drawer-backdrop is a default by TailwindCSS) or you can do:

```
data-drawer-backdrop="true"
```

In TailwindCSS docs it described [here](https://flowbite.com/docs/components/drawer/#options) as well. Look for the topic `Backdrop`.