# Tailwind CSS & Flowbite Drawer BG color

Tags: tailwind-css, navigation-drawer, flowbite

I've created a drawer element with Tailwind CSS & Flowbite. While the backdrop is good (simple gray) on light mode, it's a mix of gray and blue on dark mode, which doesn't fit the theme at all. Does anybody know how to change the backdrop color? I couldn't find any solutions for this besides turning the backdrop completely off.

There is already one [topic on Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74662812/change-tailwindcss-flowbite-drawer-background-color-effect) about it, but it doesn't help, sadly.

Any hints? Thanks for helping!

```
<div id="drawer-navigation" class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen p-4 overflow-y-auto transition-transform -translate-x-full bg-white w-80 dark:bg-zinc-800" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="drawer-navigation-label">[ELEMENTS INSIDE]</div>
```

Completely looked through the documentation of Flowbite, used Google and Stack Overflow.

Answer (score 0):

In tailwindcss there are multiple breakpoint ex: dark. The dark breakpoint define the css when darkmode is active

```
<div class="fixed top-0 left-0 z-40 h-screen p-4 overflow-y-auto transition-transform -translate-x-full bg-white w-80 dark:bg-zinc-800" tabindex="-1" aria-labelledby="drawer-navigation-label">
  [ELEMENTS INSIDE]
</div>
```

The div background is white by default defined by the bg-white class, but is the darkmode is active there is an extra class on it `dark:bg-zinc-800` defined by the `dark` breakpoint.

If you want to change the background on the dark theme you need to change the class defined by the `dark` breakpoint, in this case the `dark:bg-zinc-800` class anyway you want.

Comment: It's not about changing the color of the drawer itself, it's about the backdrop (opacity on the whole website when the drawer is shown).

Answer (score 0):

Try it?

```
    <html lang="en" className="dark">
```